# Why isn't my CSS styling applying to my HTML once uploaded to GitHub pages?

Tags: html, css, github-pages, relative-path

I made a portfolio site using HTML and external CSS. I used a relative link and as far as I can tell, it's formatted correctly.  When I open it from my editor in Chrome, all is as it should be, but when pushed up to GitHub pages, my site loses the CSS styling. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

https://github.com/cng732/Portfolio

https://cng732.github.io/Portfolio/

Comment: Please provide at least part of your code in the question. Links are not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have a small mistake in style reference

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

In your code /CSS/ in the link is uppercase. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for looking it over! It's working now :)

Comment: You are welcome! In such cases take a look into Developer tools in your web browser. You can watch all network requests made by your application there. Usually, that's enough to fix such kind of issues.